# AWS lambda list-functions command return (InvalidSignatureException) error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda

I am a first time AWS user and I am playing with Lambda. Following the offical "Getting Started" guide at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started.html I am stuck on the final command on step #1, to verify I can reach Lambda: 
`aws lambda list-functions --profile admin` (my username is admin, instead of adminuser).

Here is my config file for admin:

```
[profile admin]
output = json
region = us-west-2
```

Here is the error I keep getting:

```
An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the ListFunctions operation: Signature not yet current: 20170305T010814Z is still later than 20170304T231204Z (20170304T230704Z + 5 min.)
```

I do not have any EC2 instance or anything running, as the guide has not mentioned anything on that front yet, but I feel I have missed something fundamental here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the error message:

> An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the ListFunctions operation: Signature not yet current: 20170305T010814Z is still later than 20170304T231204Z (20170304T230704Z + 5 min.)

When the AWS SDK signs the API call, the current time (as it is on your local computer) is part of that signature. The API requires that your clock be within a certain tolerance of AWS's clocks, +/- 5 minutes I think. The error you are getting above is because the clocks are different by too big of a difference.

Check the clock on the computer you are executing your command; the computer you are seeing the `InvalidSignatureException` error.

The message says your local clock is `20170305T010814Z` which is 2017-03-05 01:08:14 UTC. It also says that AWS's clock is `20170304T230704Z`, which is 2017-03-04 23:07:04 UTC.

So it looks like your local clock is two hours ahead of the AWS's clock.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I knew it was something like that but I presumed it was a server time issue, rather than my local machine time. Simple dumb mistake but thanks.